# Superscript character in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to format time like `5h45'12"` but I'd like to make the `'h'` top index in TextView. Is there easy way to do that without making several TextViews for each part of the time?

Comment: what do you mean with top index? you mean superscript?

Comment: yes, I mean superscript :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to copy this character and use it: ʰ
It's a superscript h. So it will look like:

5ʰ45'12"

I'm not sure if this is what you like, and also not sure if it will work on Android but you can try.

Comment: Yes, that worked and it's simple. Thank you. I've noticed also SpannableStringBuilder that might be more "legit" solution